# Как выяснить, что данная строка содержит слова из определённого набора?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка содержащая слова через пробел `"style asda top red test ask"`;
И есть массив со словами `"style red"`

Мне нужно проверить содержит ли строка `"style asda top red test ask"` слова из строки `"style red"` как это сделать ?

Я так понимаю что нужно с помощью `replace` заменять пробел на какой-то символ, а потом создать из строки регулярное выражение с помощью `new RegExp("строка", "флаги")` и потом использовать `test` к созданному `RegExp`. Вообщем я не знаю на что заменить пробел и как вообще должно выглядеть регулярное выражение на подбор слов?

Comment: а ты уверен, что тебе без регулярных выражений не обойтись? Не будет ли проще использовать просто indexOf? http://javascript.ru/string/indexof

Comment: Типичная [проблема XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-x-y-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xy-problem)

Comment: Мне кажется будет хуже. Нужно же будет создавать цикл (слов в массиве может быть больше двух) и в нём проверять. Я рассматривал этот вариант, регулярные мне понравились больше

Comment: "проблема XY" ну нормально вообще ? Как ещё я могу подробнее расписать проблему ?

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы зацикливаться на регулярных выражениях, лучше распишите то, что именно вы хотите сделать, вашу **исходную** проблему. Кстати, регулярные выражения -- не единственный способ нахождения подстрок ;)

Comment: Но там же это написано в 2-ух первых абзацах и судя по первому комментарию я доступно изложил суть проблемы.

Comment: @Kirpich643, насчет "мне кажется будет хуже": на самом деле, регулярные выражения работают далеко не "на силе волшебства" - они разворачиваются в кучу вложенных циклов и условий, последовательно проходящих по тексту. Все это происходит в недрах regex-библиотек. Из-за непрозрачности данного процесса, крайне сложно составить регулярное выражение, которое не будет работать заметно медленнее, нежели простой перебор текста в цикле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При условии, что обе строки не содержат спецсимволов, можно воспользоваться как раз регулярным выражением:

Возвращает true

```js
var string = "style asda top red test ask";
var array = "style red";
var reg = new RegExp("(?=.*?(?:\\s|^)" + array.replace(/ /g, "(?:\\s|$))(?=.*?(?:\\s|^)") + "(?:\\s|$))");
alert(reg.test(string));
```

Возвращает false:

```js
var string = "style asda top red2 test ask";
var array = "style red";
var reg = new RegExp("(?=.*?(?:\\s|^)" + array.replace(/ /g, "(?:\\s|$))(?=.*?(?:\\s|^)") + "(?:\\s|$))");
alert(reg.test(string));
```

Comment: `(?:\\s|$)` лучше заменить на `\\b` - граница слова

Answer (score 1):

```
// Возвращает true, если строка have содержит все 
// слова из строки required
var containRequiredWords = function(have, required){
    var required = required.split(' ');
    var have = have.split(' ');

    for(var i = 0; i < required.length; i++){
        if(have.indexOf(required[i]) === -1){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

var have = "style asda top red test ask";

containRequiredWords(have, "style red");     // true
containRequiredWords(have, "style blue");    // false
```

Можете внутрь функции ещё и приведение строк к одному регистру добавить, если нужна регистронезависимость.

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет?

```
var words = ['style', 'red'],
  wordsReg = new RegExp(words.join('|'), 'i'),
  str = 'style asda top red test ask',
  result = str.search(wordsReg) !== -1;

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Оно вернёт true если там будет любое слова из массива, а нужно чтобы все слова из массива присутствовали в строке, вот(